# Proving existence of an optimal substructure for the DP problem "Equal" from HackerRank

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

**Q: How one would prove the existence of an optimal substructure for the following DP problem "Equal" from HackerRank?**

**Problem statement:**

---

[image]

---

**My attempt:**
Let $ A = [ a_1,a_2,...,a_n ] $ be our initial list where for all $ 1 \leq i \leq n $, $i$ is the $ith$ person and $ A[i] $ is the number of chocolates the $ ith $ person has.
Denote $ chocolate_{list} = [ 1,2,5]  $.
Suppose that in order to optimally distribute the chocolates in $ A $ there exists $ 1 \leq k_1 \leq m $ s.t. there exists $ 1 \leq q_1 \leq 3 $ s.t. we distribute $ chocolate_{list}[ q_1 ] $ to all workers except the $ k_1 th $ worker. Denote this newly created list as $ \hat{ A } $. Note that the number of ways to distribute the chocolates in $ \hat{ A } $ [by the rule that we distribute to all workers except one ] is itself the optimal number of ways to distribute the chocolates. Otherwise,  we'd have $ 1 \leq k_2 \neq k_1 \leq n $ or $ 1 \leq q_2 \neq q_2 \leq 3 $ and distribute the chocolates in $ A $ [ according to the rules given in the problem description ] and denote this new array as $ A^{'} $ . [ I stopped here because I'm not sure how to continue to find a contradiction ].

**Q: Does this DP problem even have an optimal substructure? If so what is the proof for the existence of it?**

**Notes:**
**Reminder** to the steps used when showing the existence of optimal substructure ( from CLRS ) :

> 1. You show that a solution to the problem consists of making a choice, such as
>    choosing an initial cut in a rod or choosing an index at which to split the matrix
>    chain. Making this choice leaves one or more subproblems to be solved.
> 2. You suppose that for a given problem, you are given the choice that leads to an
>    optimal solution. You do not concern yourself yet with how to determine this
>    choice. You just assume that it has been given to you.
> 3. Given this choice, you determine which subproblems ensue and how to best
>    characterize the resulting space of subproblems.
> 4. You show that the solutions to the subproblems used within an optimal solution
>    to the problem must themselves be optimal by using a “cut-and-paste” technique.
>    You do so by supposing that each of the subproblem solutions is not
>    optimal and then deriving a contradiction. In particular, by “cutting out” the
>    nonoptimal solution to each subproblem and “pasting in” the optimal one, you
>    show that you can get a better solution to the original problem, thus contradicting
>    your supposition that you already had an optimal solution. If an optimal solution gives rise to more than one subproblem, they are typically so similar
>    that you can modify the cut-and-paste argument for one to apply to the others
>    with little effort.

**(  since it might help, i'm providing an example for proof of the existence of optimal substructure of different problem: )** Example of proving the existence of an optimal substructure for the matrix parenthization problem ( CLRS , chapter 15.2 ):
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: We require you to credit hte original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing  This appears to be copied from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal/problem without attribution.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: I wrote down the problem's from "HackerRank" ,was that extremely hard to miss the attribution? .

Comment: I didn't miss that.  We expect you to provide a more specific attribution, including a link to the original source.  See the guidelines that I already linked to: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Ok, I'll add the links themselves next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle o_1, o_2, o_{m+1}\rangle$ be a non-empty optimal sequence of operations that distributes the chocolates evenly, i.e., such that the final distribution is $[k,k,k, \dots, k]$.

Let $\alpha_i$ be the number of candies given to the $i$-th person by operation $o_{m+1}$ and consider the subsequence of operations $\langle o_1, o_2, \dots, o_m\rangle$. We need to show that  $\langle o_1, o_2, \dots, o_m\rangle$ is an optimal sequence of operations to obtain the final distribution $[k-\alpha_1, k-\alpha_2, \dots, k-\alpha_n]$.

The proof is by contradiction. Suppose that  $\langle o_1, o_2, \dots, o_m\rangle$ is not optimal, hence there is some sequence of operations $\langle o'_1, o'_2, \dots, o'_\ell \rangle$ that yields the final distribution $[k-\alpha_1, k-\alpha_2, \dots, k-\alpha_n]$ and such that $\ell < m$.
Therefore, the sequence $\langle o'_1, o'_2, \dots, o'_\ell, o_{m+1} \rangle$ yields the distribution $[(k-\alpha_1) + \alpha_1, (k-\alpha_2) + \alpha_2, \dots, (k-\alpha_n) + \alpha_n] = [k, k, \dots, k]$.
The number of operations of the above sequence is $\ell + 1$ and, by the optimality of $\langle o_1, o_2, \dots, o_{m+1}\rangle$, we know that $\ell+1 \ge m+1$  since every sequence that yields $[k,k,\dots,k]$ must consist of at least $m+1$ operations.
This results in the contradiction $m+1 \le \ell+1 < m+1$.

Comment: Marvelous!, a question: why $ o'_{m+1} $  isn't necessarily $ o_{m+1} $? or are they the same?

Comment: @hazelnut_116, you are right, that was a typo. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Last question: do you know of good books that teach how to apply pure math and proof techniques to programming concepts? besides CLRS?